# When I am building a deep learning model for automatic source code comment generating. I got below error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

[image]
When I am building a deep learning model for automatic source code comment generating. I got the above error. I used the transformer model for creating the model.Can anybody give me a solution

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using the [transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/configuration_transfo_xl.html) module. According to the documentation, the order in which parameters are provided is:

```
 def __init__(
        self,
        vocab_size=267735,
        cutoffs=[20000, 40000, 200000],
        d_model=1024,
        d_embed=1024,
        n_head=16,
        d_head=64,
        d_inner=4096,
        div_val=4,
        pre_lnorm=False,
        n_layer=18,
        mem_len=1600,
        clamp_len=1000,
        same_length=True,
        proj_share_all_but_first=True,
        attn_type=0,
        sample_softmax=-1,
        adaptive=True,
        dropout=0.1,
        dropatt=0.0,
        untie_r=True,
        init="normal",
        init_range=0.01,
        proj_init_std=0.01,
        init_std=0.02,
        layer_norm_epsilon=1e-5,
        eos_token_id=0,
        **kwargs
    )
```

Since you didn't provide the proper names to the constructor, it has associated `n_x_vocab` to `vocab_size` and `n_y_vocab` to `cutoffs`.  so the required parameters `n_head`, `d_inner`, `n_layer`, and `d_head` are considered missing.

Once you provide the parameters in the appropriate order and/or explicitly name the parameter, like you did in `d_model = 256`, this error should be fixed.